# How scanner class works for String "1 a 10 . 100 sfn 1000"

Tags: java

I was asked this program question in interview.

```
String test = "1 a 10 . 100 sfn 1000";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(test);
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    total = total + scan.nextInt(); //not sure if this was the exact line but something like this
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you try out the code to see what it does?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException Getting thi if try it in eclipse

Comment: I am feeling may be I am missing some part from what was there in question sheet. So wanted to know how scanner works for that kinda String

Comment: This question cannot really be answered - the code posted doesn't work. To make it work, it would be different code. Maybe the interview question was a trick one?

Answer (score -1):

I tried alternatives and here I am with the answer
[It will scan first int and print it in console after which exception will be thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PHot.png)

So in my case, I was given with 4 choices, 1, 11, 111 and 1111 so answer is 1.

Comment: Don't post the code as image, please. It can't be copied and pasted, users relying on screen readers can't read it, and images are blocked in some places. Edit the answer with the actual code in plain text, please.